# Make transparent "star"-looking hole in UIView

Tags: ios

Let's say I have some UIView and also I have a "closed" UIBezierPath inside of that view. What I want to achieve is to have everything "outside" this path be white and inside - transparent (like a hole of that path-shape). Solutions like [this](http://jslim.net/blog/2014/06/13/uiview-fill-with-color-and-leave-a-empty-square-in-center/) don't work, for some reason, part of the shape inside is also white.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `view.layer.mask` property to make holes in a a view.

I'm using this piece of code to make mask from images, but you could also just draw you `UIBezierPath` to `CALayer` and use that instead.

```
/*
 Get a layer that can be used to mask an image. All pixels with alpha 0 in mask image will be hidden
 use as:
 self.view.layer.mask = <Mask returned from this call>
 self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
 */
+(CALayer*)getMaskLayerFromImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
    mask.contents =(id) image.CGImage;
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    return mask;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this thing by using UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer

> I am taking outlet of view from storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
```

> Create an object of UIBezierPath()

```
var path = UIBezierPath()
```

> Create a method which take center of view and we create another UIBezierPath() as **circlePath** which is circle and we append the circle on previous UIBezierPath() **path**.
>   Know take a CAShapeLayer and cut the **circlePath** 
>   Change center point to draw circle on specific point.

```
func overLay() {
    let sizes = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: self.view.center, size: sizes))
    path.append(circlePath)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer() //create the mask layer
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath // Give the mask layer the path you just draw
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd // Cut out the intersection part
    myView.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

[image]

Comment: Once you take a "star" path, not a circle, you will get the issue I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: So you want to add a start just like I added circle?

Comment: Yes, I need such shape.